# Rate of change in de Broglie wavelength in nth orbit.

Tags: black-holes, photons, orbital-motion

Suppose I want to calculate the rate of change in de Broglie wavelength of a photon in any orbit number "n" around the black hole. Let it's original de Broglie wavelength be "λ" and the de Broglie wavelength in nth orbit be "λ^n" . Then how to calculate the rate of change in its de Broglie wavelength in nth orbit as a function of the rate of change in original de Broglie wavelength and the orbit in which the photon is present. Please keep the explanation simple. Thanks.